# Problema em recuperar com Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Oque está acontecendo é o seguinte, quando eu clico no botão(mLikebtn) ela adiciona 1 valor a child Like no firebase se eu clicar de novo remove(Mecânica de Like mesmo)... o problema é quando saio do atividade atual e retorno , ou quando saio do app e retorno, o valor da TextView não aparece mais consta no Firebase , só aparece se clicar nela de novo 2x.(porque se clicar de novo retira a child, e volta quando clica de mais uma vez).

Agradeço a quem puder me ajudar.

```
        mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            mCurtidas.setText(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + "");

            }
            }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
         });

        mLikebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        mProcessLike = true;

        mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (mProcessLike) {


                if (dataSnapshot.child(currentUserId).hasChild(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {

                    mDatabaseLike.child(currentUserId).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();
                    mProcessLike = false;

                } else {
                    mDatabaseLike.child(currentUserId).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue("curtidas");
                    mProcessLike = false;


                }
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Atualização**

```
        mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Log.e(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child(post_key)),dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + "");

            for (DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //Log.e(String.valueOf(snap.child(currentUserId).toString()),snap.getChildrenCount() + "");
                mCurtidas.setText(dataSnapshot.child(currentUserId).getChildrenCount() + "");
            }}
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });


                mLikebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    mProcessLike = true;

    mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Log.e(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child(post_key)),dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + "");


                // mDatabaseLike.child("curtidas").setValue(String.valueOf(snap.child(currentUserId)),snap.getChildrenCount()+ "");

            if (mProcessLike) {


                if (dataSnapshot.child(currentUserId).hasChild(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {

                    mDatabaseLike.child(currentUserId).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();
                    mProcessLike = false;

                } else {
                    mDatabaseLike.child(currentUserId).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue("curtidas");
                    mProcessLike = false;


                }
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Minhas Perguntas sem respostas:
[Problema em recuperar dados em mapa (Firebase)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/182694/problema-em-recuperar-dados-em-mapa-firebase)

Comment: Seu listener esta dentro do onclick do botão.

Coloque ele fora, toda vez que você alterar algo no firebases, ele será chamado.
Use o OnClick para alterar. Para recuperar utilize o listerner do firebase, em qualquer lugar.

Comment: não consegui acompanhar..

Comment: no caso eu teria que fazer uma para esse trecho...for (DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //Log.e(String.valueOf(snap.child(currentUserId).toString()),snap.getChildrenCount() + "");
                mCurtidas.setText(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + "");
?

Comment: Você esta errando na logica do databases. 

Os Listener precisa ficar na Class principal. Ele fica escultando o database, e qualquer mudança ele é alterado e chama o public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}
Também é chamado quando quando a activity é aberta, então você pode usar esse momento para recuperar o comentario e preencher o que precisar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precisa fazer uma mudança parecida com isso.

```
  mLikebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v){

            //Aqui você faz a mudança que precisar.
            //Apois mudar, o mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { será chamado de novo.

            if (dataSnapshot.child(currentUserId).hasChild(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {

                mDatabaseLike.child(currentUserId).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();
                mProcessLike = false;


            } else {
                mDatabaseLike.child(currentUserId).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue("curtidas");
                mProcessLike = false;


            }
    }
}

mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        //Log.e(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child(post_key)),dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + "");

        for (DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            //Log.e(String.valueOf(snap.child(currentUserId).toString()),snap.getChildrenCount() + "");
            mCurtidas.setText(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + "");

        }
        // mDatabaseLike.child("curtidas").setValue(String.valueOf(snap.child(currentUserId)),snap.getChildrenCount()+ "");

    }


    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Não deu ainda continua do mesmo jeito,editei como está o código agora]

Comment: segui o seu o conceito do seu raciocínio e deu certo valeu!

Comment: não entendi muito bem porque não funcionou na primeira,mCurtidas.setText(dataSnapshot.child(currentUserId).getChildrenCount() + ""); mudei essa linha pra pegar os like por id do post e já deu a diferença junto

Comment: funcionou, deu certo?

Comment: Sim, Valeu mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

Use o método:

```
@Override <br>OnStart(){
  //Coloque o que você precisa carregar quando iniciar
};
```

Ele vai carregar o que você precisa primeiro;