# Problema com Menupop

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Olá, então já não é a primeira vez que venho tendo problema com RecyclerView.ViewHolder, neste caso agora acontece o seguinte, Meu menu tem 2 botões estou tentando pegar o clique com **switch (item.getItemId())** Realmente não sei se este é o certo mais quando tento fazer algo simples  como abrir uma atividade não consigo já que pede pra botar a ViewH como, not Static, ai não aparece nenhum erro aparente mais quando rodo o app logo aparece o erro **java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:  class android.view.View** ...
tentei botar em uma classe separada mais ai veio outros problemas que não resolver também. 
não sei se fui claro o suficiente com a pergunta caso não, me perguntem que acrescento algo.

A nível de informação, não vou trabalhar abrindo activity, farei isso [Como Faço para editar uma child no firebase?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/186260/como-fa%c3%a7o-para-editar-uma-child-no-firebase/186265?noredirect=1#comment385243_186265)
e apagar childs.

```
public class BloviewHolderr extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;
    ImageButton mMenuPopup;
    Context mContext;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase1;
    public BloviewHolderr(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
        mMenuPopup = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.menuComentario);

        mMenuPopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mContext = mView.getContext();
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, mMenuPopup);
                //Inflando o popup usando o arquivo xml
                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_comentarioo, popup.getMenu());

                //Resgata o item clicado e mostra em um Toast
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.apagar:
                                Intent singleBlogIntent = new Intent (Comentarios.this, FloatChat.class);
                                startActivity(singleBlogIntent);
                        // read the listItemPosition here
                                // read the listItemPositionForPopupMenu here
                                return true;
                            default:
                                return false;
                        }
                    }});

                popup.show();;
                }
            });
        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem como você colocar o seu menu_comentarioo.xlm?

Comment: como funciona pra botar alguma ação no clique, eu estava tentando abrir uma atividade e não consegui, depois tentei fazer uma ação simples no firebase também não consegui

Comment: acho que não está funcionando o clique do modo que estou fazendo  public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.apagar:

Comment: Pelo que estou vendo, o click no item está funcionando perfeitamente. Olha só: tirei o intent e coloquei um toast https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxfzFAS7MTC0bktGNmdFNVRVOHM

Comment: então deve ser a intente já que nem o toast eu consegui usar

Comment: quando eu tento usar uma intenção que abre uma atividade a activity aparece grifada e quando tento resolver aprece pra tirar o static(public **static** class BloviewHolderr extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{) então se eu faço isso a atividade da erro depois (java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: class android.view.View)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54339/discussion-between-ack-lay-and-wallace-roberto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não vejo nenhum problema com o *click* no item em relação ao `PopupMenu`. Use o contexto no qual a *view* está sendo exibida. Então podes modificar seu `Intent` inserindo o `mContext` desta forma:

```
Intent singleBlogIntent = new Intent (mContext, FloatChat.class);
mContext.startActivity(singleBlogIntent);
```